# All-rounder hardware recommendations for sound design/synthesis

Tags: synthesis

Hi there,

Apologies in advance for the dull question. I'm seeking some buyer's advice. I've currently got a Roland Juno 6, Korg MS-2000 and Teenage Engineering OP-1 as hardware synthesisers, as well as an Akai MPC-1000 that I use mostly for music.

I'm looking to possibly shore up my ability to generate more complex timbres and textures in hardware. I can probably afford to spend up to around AUD$2000 (similar to USD), and I prefer to buy secondhand things.

I know there's a lot of talk of recorders and plugins, but I haven't been able to find much synth advice in other threads. What are your indispensables, or recommendations within that vague price range?

I much prefer to have hands-on control of as much as possible. The main things that have crossed my radar to date are the **Waldorf Blofeld**, **Access Virus Ti Polar** (if I can ever find a used one), a **small modular system** (Analogue Solutions Telemetry or similar), **Elektron Analog Four**, **Studiologic Sledge** or (though not a synth, but for processing and sample manipulation) **Elektron Octatrack**.

Do you have any advice or other recommendations?  I'm just looking for a diverse and somewhat affordable machine that will help me broaden my palette.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Kyma.

http://www.symbolicsound.com/cgi-bin/bin/view/Company/WebHome

Technically not in the specified price range though.

Comment: Yikes! Full on leap.

Comment: So worth it though if you can afford it.  Kyma/Paca is a mindblowing piece of software/hardware.  Would love to be able to afford this myself.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try to find a used Nord Modular G2X or a Kurzweil K2500/K2600 (with KDFX included). Both are great synth with huge sonic capabilities. I used to own both long time ago and both are amazing machines :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always go the modular synthesis route.

Mutable Instruments is great for producing textures. I use an Elements into Clouds for drones and layered pads. I use Plaits for monophonic synth leads and drum patterns. You can get some very basic and powerful modules for pretty cheap.

I would stay away from the Waldorf Blofeld. I have one and it has caused nothing but issues.